# configure lein-cloverage from project.clj

Tags: clojure, code-coverage, leiningen

I started using [cloverage](https://github.com/cloverage/cloverage) with [leiningen](https://leiningen.org/). I want to excude calls to `assert` from the coverage report.

The following command works fine for me:

`$ lein cloverage --exclude-call clojure.core/assert`

However, when I put `:cloverage {:exclude-call ["clojure.core/assert"]}` into the `project.clj` file and I just call `$ lein cloverage`, then the parameter is ignored.

How should I configure cloverage from my leiningen project file?

EDIT: I understand that I could create an alias easily with the followings, however, I would prefer configuring it a cleaner way:

```
:aliases      {"coverage" ["cloverage" "--exclude-call" "clojure.core/assert"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you found a solution. For anyone coming across this post now:

I put the cloverage options under my test profile in my `project.clj`. So, you could try something like this in `project.clj`:

```
:profiles {:test {:cloverage {:exclude-call ["clojure.core/assert"]}}}
```

When I run cloverage from the command line, I have to do `$ lein with-profile test cloverage`.

Also, here's the post I used when figuring this out: [Can I make lein cloverage skip specific tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47644349/can-i-make-lein-cloverage-skip-specific-tests)

Comment: The fn to exclude shouldn't be quoted and instead should be a symbol, i.e.
clojure.core/assert instead of "clojure.core/assert"

Comment: @AnmolVijaywargiya that is correct, it should not be there in quotes !